# UICollectionViewCell not appearing

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm creating a `UICollectionView` programmatically.

As a disclaimer, I followed this tutorial: http://randexdev.com/2014/07/uicollectionview/

So my setup is as follows:

I have a storyboard with a `UIScrollView` which is controlled by `ViewControllerA`.

In a separate class `CustomCollectionViewController` I have the following code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class CustomCollectionViewController : UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {

        let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 90, height: 120)

        super.init(collectionViewLayout: layout)

        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        //collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 500), collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView!.dataSource = self
        collectionView!.delegate = self
        collectionView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        collectionView!.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        self.view.addSubview(collectionView!)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 14
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        return cell
    }
}
```

In my `ViewControllerA` I have this code

```
let collectionViewController: CustomCollectionViewController = CustomCollectionViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
collectionViewController.view.frame.origin = CGPointMake(scrollViewWidth*3, 0)

scrollView.addSubview(collectionViewController.view)
```

If run in the simulator, I can see the red background of the `UICollectionView`, but no cells whatsoever.

Any hints what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint in your collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath: function and see if it gets called?

Comment: @dirkgroten I already did. It is being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't set the `ViewController` as `childViewController` in the `viewControllerA`

```
self.addChildViewController(collectionViewController)
collectionViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

Answer (score 1):

May be  `-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` is missing!

Comment: I just tried and added `func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize { return CGSizeMake(90, 120) }`, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Your view controller is subclass of UICollectionViewController try changing it to UIViewController OR try self.collectionView = yourCollectionView

Comment: Nope. No change whatsoever.